# How to search an independent word in a mySQL search?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, sqlite

I am trying to find the word `fox` in the sentence `The foxy brown fox jumped over the lazy dog`.
Currently, I search using the following SQL:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sentences 
 WHERE sentence LIKE '%fox%'
```

This finds the sentence due to the presence of foxy, not just fox. How do I find `fox` independently?

I am implementing this search in Ruby on Rails, and so the syntax for the above SQL would be translated to the following:

```
query = 'fox'
result = Sentence.where("sentence LIKE :search_term", {:search_term => "%#{query}%"})
```

Comment: Text search on databases is slow, expensive and does not scale. You should consider moving this to a full text search solution like Solr os Sphinx if this is a production application.

Comment: Full Text Search (FTS) is the SQL functionality to provide what you want -- REGEX will work, but never outperform FTS or `LIKE`.

Comment: Why does this question have the "ruby" tag?

Comment: @Andrew - because I am implementing this in Ruby on Rails. I'll edit the tags so they are more specific and mention it in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the REGEXP facility along with "word boundary" expressions. `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`.  For example

```
SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE sentence REGEXP '[[:<:]]fox[[:>:]]'
```

This will handle cases where 'fox' is preceded or followed by a comma, start/end of string, or other non-word character.  A word character is defined as `[_A-Za-z0-9]`.  Here's a link to the doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this doesn't seem to work with SQLite3 and Ruby on Rails 3.1. I keep getting `SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: REGEXP`. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I figured some other people might have this question, so I posted a separate one right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839204/how-to-turn-on-regexp-in-rails-3-1-and-sqlite-3